# Force git to update my local repo when pulling

Tags: git

I have some local changes in my local repo (in my computer) which i dont want to commit. Now i am going to take a pull request from my master repo but it says, "Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge".

So how can I force git to update my local repo by override those local changes when take a pull request?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve - if you don't want to commit them, and you want those changes to be overwritten and lost, why not just reset/checkout locally before pulling? If you want to keep the changes and then apply them afterwards, use stash...

Comment: reset/checkout locally means manually delete my changes in order to sync with master? even after that since my local file has been changed, git might tell me to do a commit

Comment: No, it means use "git checkout" or "git reset" to get *git* to undo your local changes.

Comment: ok thanks. i have did a git hard reset. Btw what is the difference of git checkout and reset

Comment: I would suggest reading the documentation very carefully :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. If you want to drop your changes completely that you've worked on since your last commit, do a

   `git reset HEAD --hard`

   **Be aware that you can't undo that command**
2. You can also stash does changes (eg put them in a location to reuse later, but this will never be shared when you push/pull)

   `git stash`

   And if you want to apply (recover) the latest stash, you can do

   `git stash pop`

I'd rather go with `2.`, so that you don't loose your changes in case you need them later.

You would do :

```
git stash
git pull <remote> <branch>
```